# Reading and Writing text file in Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Following is the code to first save a line of text,into a text file,present in azure storage, and then read it and print .

```
string firstString = "this \t is \n a \t line \n are: ";            

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                memoryStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(firstString), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(firstString).Length);
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
            }

            string text;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
                text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
                Trace.WriteLine(text);
            }
```

Problem is that nothing gets printed in the Trace.Writeline() Statement.

First i thought,that it might be a encoding issue,so i changed the format of my text file from ASCII to UTF8, but still nothing gets printed.
WHat am i missing here,any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following line of code:

```
 using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                memoryStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(firstString), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(firstString).Length);
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
            }
```

with

```
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        memoryStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(firstString), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(firstString).Length);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        blob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
    }
```

What's happening is that when you write the byte array to `memoryStream`, you're not resetting the position of stream to 0 thus a 0 byte blob is being uploaded.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri 
What is the solution when it is bitmap image (not text)

Comment: @BasharAbuShamaa Same solution. The same should work.

Comment: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MyBitMapImg) doesn't work!

Comment: aah .... I see. That will work for text based data and not binary data. You would need to use functions on Bitmap images to read the stream. You may want to post your problem as a separate question.

Comment: Yes, I did, thank you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784058/when-upload-bitmap-stream-to-azure-storage-it-store-zero-empty-image

Answer (score 0):

When you use `MemoryStream` you first write to memory and after the write from memory to blob, it is better to write directly to blob, example:

```
    using (var blobStream = blockBlob.OpenWrite())
    {
        var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(firstString);
        blobStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
```