# When upload Bitmap stream to Azure storage, it store zero/empty image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, cloud

I am using below code to upload a MemoryStream from a bitmap image to my Microsoft azure storage account:

```
                         MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                       img.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                       blob.Properties.ContentType = model.File.ContentType;
                       blob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
```

What happen by use above code is it uploads an empty image to Azure storage :( !(I found the name but the file size is zero!)!

```
       if (model.File != null && model.File.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    Bitmap original = null;
                    var name = "newimagefile";
                    var errorField = string.Empty;

                    errorField = "File";
                    name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(model.File.FileName);
                    original = Bitmap.FromStream(model.File.InputStream) as Bitmap;
                   if (original != null)
                     {
                       var img = CreateImage(original, model.X, model.Y, model.Width, model.Height);



                       CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                                   CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

                       CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                       CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("company"); // must always be lowercase
                                                 container.CreateIfNotExists();

                       container.SetPermissions(
       new BlobContainerPermissions
       {
           PublicAccess =
               BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
       });


                       CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(imgName + ".png");

                       MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                       img.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                       blob.Properties.ContentType = model.File.ContentType;
                       blob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
```

}

Any Help please !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to set the position back to the start of the stream before uploading

```
img.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
blob.Properties.ContentType = model.File.ContentType;
memoryStream.Position = 0;
blob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
```